# Compare 2 inputs to calculate commission with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, laravel

I need to make a comparison of 2 inputs and the one with the lower price multiply it by the percentage and insert the result in the commission input, only I'm not very good with js, the list price is written down by the user, the percentage and the sale comes from a DB so you have to compare the list price with the sale price and the one with the lower price is the one that should be multiplied by the percentage

```js
<script>
    // generamos un evento click y keyup para cada elemento input con la clase .input
var input=document.querySelectorAll(".input");
input.forEach(function(e) {
    e.addEventListener("click",multiplica);
    e.addEventListener("keyup",multiplica);
});

// funcion que genera la multiplicacion
function multiplica() {

    // nos posicionamos en el tr del producto
    var tr=this.closest("tr");

    var total=1;

    // recorremos todos los elementos del tr que tienen la clase .input
    var inputs=tr.querySelectorAll(".input");
    inputs.forEach(function(e) {
        total*=e.value;
    });

    // mostramos el total con dos decimales
    tr.querySelector(".total").value=total.toFixed(2);

    // indicamos que calcule el total
    calcularTotal(this.closest("table"));
}

// funcion que calcula la suma total de los productos
function calcularTotal(e) {
    var total=0;

    // obtenemos todos los totales y los sumamos
    var totales=e.querySelectorAll(".total");
    totales.forEach(function(e) {
        total+=parseFloat(e.value);
    });

    // mostramos la suma total con dos decimales
    e.getElementsByClassName("totales")[0].value=total.toFixed(2);
}
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td>
                                        <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
                                            <input type="number" value="{{$ventas->PORCENTAJE}}" class="input form-control" id="porcentaje"
                                                style="width:120px;height:40px">
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                      <td>
                                        <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
                                            <input type="number"  class="input form-control" id="preciolista"
                                                style="width:120px;height:40px">
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                      <td>
                                        <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
                                            <input type="text" class="total form-control" id="comision"
                                                style="width:60px;height:40px">
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
                                            <input type="text" value="{{$ventas->IMPORTE}}" class="form-control" name="venta" id="venta"
                                                style="width:120px;height:40px">
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
```

Until now my script allows to multiply the percentage by the list price and put the result in the commission field

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have quite a lot going on in your JavaScript and I'm not sure how much is relevant (I don't know any Spanish I'm afraid).

To demonstrate how you might achieve this as simply as possible, I have used the basic of markup.

**HTML**

```
<label for="porcentaje">Percentage</label>
<input type="number" name="porcentaje" id="porcentaje" class="comision-input" value="10" />

<label for="preciolista">Price List</label>
<input type="text" name="preciolista" id="preciolista" class="comision-input" value="7" />

<label for="venta">Sale</label>
<input type="text" name="venta" id="venta" class="comision-input" value="5" />

<label for="comision">Commission</label>
<input type="text" name="comision" id="comision" readonly value="0" />

<button id="btn-calculate-comision">Calculate</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  // Define variables we'll use for accessing our elements
  const porcentaje = document.querySelector("#porcentaje");
  const preciolista = document.querySelector("#preciolista");
  const venta = document.querySelector("#venta");
  const comision = document.querySelector("#comision");
  const btn = document.querySelector("#btn-calculate-comision");
  const comisionInputs = document.querySelectorAll(".comision-input");

  // Define the function that will perform the calculation
  calculateComision = () => {
    // JavaScript has a Math.min() function
    //  this returns the smallest of the numbers it is supplied
    comision.value =
      porcentaje.value * Math.min(preciolista.value, venta.value);
  };

  // Attach event listeners to the elements
  // input could be replaced with blur 
  //  blur is triggered when the input loses focus
  comisionInputs.forEach((el) => {
    el.addEventListener("input", function () {
      calculateComision();
    });
  });

  // Alternatively, you could attach event listeners to each element individually
  //  useful if you need to perform input element specific functionality

  //   porcentaje.addEventListener("input", function () {
  //     calculateComision();
  //   })

  //   preciolista.addEventListener("input", function () {
  //     calculateComision();
  //   });

  //   venta.addEventListener("input", function (e) {
  //     calculateComision();
  //   });

  btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    calculateComision();
  });

  calculateComision();
});
```

Here is a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/peppermintology/pen/GRdbRbE) showing this in action.